# Set Realm Schema Version

Tags: ios, swift, migration, realm

I am new to Realm, and new to migrations in general. My question is if I have a couple of migrations set up, what happens when a user downloads the app for the first time? Will the newly downloaded app go through all of the migrations? Or will it just use the most up to date schema version? Is the default Realm schema version set to 0?

I am using Swift and here is the code I am using:

```
    // Realm Migration Schema Versions.
    let migrationBlock: RLMMigrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            migration.enumerateObjects(*CLASSNAMEHERE*.className()) { oldObject, newObject in

                // Perform migration here.

            }
            println("Migration for Schema Version 1 complete.")
        }


    }
    RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmSchemaVersion(1, withMigrationBlock: migrationBlock)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Realm, you migrate from the on-disk schema version to the schema version you have specified. You are correct in thinking that the schema version begins at zero, so the migration you provided will be run even when the user runs the app for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Current schema version should be set in the app via realm configuration. So that new users won't go through the migration.